# Fitting a function with a heavyside step function

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a function to a part of the following graph:
[image]

I want to find out the time the signal starts increasing exponentially. To do this I fit an exponential curve to the data, multiplied by a heavyside step function.

```
def fit(x, a, b, c, d, e):
    return np.heaviside(x-a, 0.5)*b*np.exp(c*x-d)+e

parameter, covariance = curve_fit(fit, fitx, fity)

x = np.linspace(min(fitx), max(fitx), 1000)
plt.plot(fitx, fity)
plt.plot(x, fit(x, *parameter), 'b-', label='fit')
plt.show()
```

The result is somehow a straight line

[image]

When I fit only the exponential part I get the following graph:

[image]

I'd expect a straight line at the x-axis, followed by the exponential graph in image 2. Does anybody know where I went wrong?

Comment: Might be that you need to supply a reasonable starting point for your parameter `a`.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel that helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: I'd say 70% of the problem with fitting are bad starting points, the rest mostly badly defined fit functions. I'll put the comment as an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *exponential increase*? First it decreases and then it increases with some oscillations. Which side do you want to fit? If the function is of type `( 1 - exp( -x ) )`, would the step function be better suited outside the parenthesis? Moreover, fitting the step function is always a bit tricky, as position shifts smaller than data density do not change `chi**2`. There are several posts on SE dealing with this, though.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely situation is that you have an issue with convergence of the parameters. In most cases, this convergence problem is due to bad starting points for the parameters.

Since it works as expected without the heavyside function, my guess would be that you should give a reasonable starting point for your parameter `a` in the `curve_fit` function call.

Comment: To help in finding a starting point for non-linear solvers, scipy has added the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution genetic algorithm module. Because it uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, it requires bounds on the possible parameter values within which to search - however these bounds can be quite generous. I have used this scipy module to generate initial parameter estimates for fitting a double Lorentzian peak equation to Raman spectroscopy data of carbon nanotubes here: https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/ramanspectroscopyfit

Comment: Cool to know about that.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to find "the time the signal starts increasing exponentially", but the signal plotted does not increase exponentially. In fact, it decreases (at least going in increasing time and left to right). and looks peak-like.   Do you mean that you want to fit some function to that drop?

I'd guess that a Gaussian might work well.  Using a step function might be OK too, but probably won't fit well above t=1e-8 or so.

You didn't include data or complete code, so it's hard to give a concrete example.  But you might find the lmfit package helpful here.  It has a builtin Step Model that can use a linear or error function or logistic curve. See http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#step-like-models. This might be close to what you're trying to do.